# Change email using UserManager.ChangeEmailAsync()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to give my users the ability to change email. I'd like to send a verification email as well, in which they can verify/confirm their email.

I'd just like to know more about the flow of this, and I haven't been able to find reasonable documentation online.

I see the flow like this:

1. User enters the new email they wish to use
2. Code/Token is created together with the confirmation email (the new email is not yet applied to the user)
3. Confirmation email is sent to the new email
4. User confirms/verifies their new email
5. New email and code is received in the controller and the **`UserManager.ChangeEmailAsync(User user, string newEmail, string code)`** is invoked

Is the new email applied to the user when the **`ChangeEmailAsync()`** method is invoked, or do I have to apply the new email before sending the confirmation email (*set `EmailConfirmed` back to `false`*)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Identity Email/Username change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25570025/net-identity-email-username-change)

Comment: See the second answer to this ^^^^ question - talks about confirming email via link.

Comment: I'm having problems seeing this as best practice since you just add a new property to the user class. Besides, this is not using the `UserManager.ChangeEmailAsync` approach, this is just copying the functionality from the `ConfirmEmail` scaffold that comes with a fresh MVC with identity. If there is no other exampels on using `ChangeEmailAsync`, I guess I'll need to do as he does.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
`tring code = await UserManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync("ChangeEmail",userID);`
 in SendingEmail() to the new email and save the new email in a temporary table

the function when the user confirm the new e-mail:
`

```
             public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangeEmail(ChangeEmailModel model) 
             {
                   try
                   {
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(model.Code);                   
                if ( !UserManager.VerifyUserToken(model.UserId, "ChangeEmail", model.Code)) //to verify the code
                {
                    _logger.Error($"token expired");
                    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new KeyValuePair<String, String>(Messages.ExpiredLink, CommonMessages.ExpiredLink)));
                }
                else
                {
                    UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager = new UserDetailsManager();
                    string Email = userDetailsManager.GetNewEmail(model.UserId);//get the new email from the temporary table
                    var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(model.UserId);
                    user.Email = Email;//change the email
                    user.UserName = Email;
                    result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in result.Errors)
                        {
                            if (item.Contains("already"))
                            {
                                _logger.Info("In ChangeEmail user already exists");
                                return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new KeyValuePair<String, String>(Messages.EmailUserExist, CommonMessages.EmailUserExist)));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error($"In ChangeEmail Error - {ex.Message} return {HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError}");
            return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new KeyValuePair<String, String>(Messages.InternalServerError, CommonMessages.InternalServerError)));
        }
        _logger.Info($"ChangeEmail end status {HttpStatusCode.OK} ");
        return Ok("Success");
    }`
```

this function also Overrides the preoccupation with the confirmEmail